# Putting XML Data into the Windows Event Log

Tags: c#, .net, xml, event-viewer

How can I write XML data into the Windows Event Log?

I have noticed that there is a way to insert XML into the windows event log (and not by just stuffing it into the description). The effect is that you get just your description message in the `General` view on Windows Vista. You can see your XML data in the `Details` view.

If you select the `Friendly` radio button, it appears under the `Event Data` node. If you select the XML view, then you get to see the XML.

I thought that the rawData byte array in the `EventLog.WriteEntry()` method would allow me to do this. I tried stuffing the output of XMLWriter into it. That put data into the event log, but it is viewed as binary instead of XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, in order to write xml to the Crimson/Vista event log you will have create and register a manifest that will give you the appropriate channels and events.  Then you have to compile the manifest using the [Message Compiler (mc.exe) in the WindowsSDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2009/02/03/released-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-3-5-sp1-beta.aspx).

Then if you want to log from C# you will want to create a managed provider to wrap the event logging API.  This is a little harder because you will have to use PInvoke to get at the API.

There are blog posts on how to do this whole process [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/daiken/archive/2005/09.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You have a sample in [Windows SDK (ver 6.1)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&displaylang=en) called EventProvider.
Its a C# provider (needs Vista and up to work) that uses the new Event log API (AKA crimson).
This sample show how to add custom data (amount other things).

Comment: that link now returns a 404